# Defaulting a lookup field

Tags: defaults

I have the following structure:

```
Account--<Contract --< Coverage --< Address
```

and also, on Address we have a lookup to account:

```
Account--<Address
```

I am adding my Addresses on Contract, so the Contract lookup field is automatically populated. Is there a way (without code) to automatically populate the account lookup on address?

Tia.

Comment: Look into workflow rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative to code is the new "Process Builder" which can also be turned on in your org. You can use the lookup field on the contract to update the lookup field on the Account.  I tested it out with a different lookup field so it definitely works and was pretty simple to set up. 
Once you have it turned on you will find it in the "Workflow Rules" section:
[image]

1. Click on "Processes" -> "New Process" -> Click "Add Object"
2. Next select the object you want this to fire on and when (created or
   created and edited)
3. Click on "Add Criteria" (enter criteria similar to workflow rule criteria)
4. Click on "Immediate Action" -> Select the related Account object -> then the lookup field to update -> switch to field value and select the contract lookup field to populate it with.

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently update lookup fields with workflow field updates.

That leaves 2 alternatives:

1. use the new flow triggers (without screens). You need to have
   this activated for your org first.
   https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_flow_actions.htm&language=en_US
2. create an apex trigger